# What are Modules in aspnetBoilerplate?

Tags: dependency-injection, domain-driven-design, aspnetboilerplate

aspnetBoilerplate is based on **Domain Driven Design** design pattern.

I [see](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Module-System) that aspnetBoilerplate  compose an application using **modules**.

I didn't understand what a module is  , i [searched](https://culttt.com/2014/12/10/modules-domain-driven-design/) it's definition in the context of domain driven design and i found that it serves as a container for a specific set of classes of an application.

So does that means ,For example , in c# namespace is a module because it can contains many classes ?

But even with this definition , it's not clear in the context of aspnetBoilerplate, a module defintion in aspnetBoilerplate have this structure :

```
  public class MyBlogApplicationModule : AbpModule
 {
     public override void Initialize()
     {
        IocManager.RegisterAssemblyByConvention(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
     }
  }
```

so it's just one class,that have one method !

Also what is the relationship between model and dependency injection ?

Why there is a registration of the model as a service in an IocContainer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Abp module is just a way for you to organize your code under the same domain/layer and at the same time still being able to configure/interact with other modules

E.g. your module is a separate library project that contains certain domain logic, to initialize your module correctly, you can place the initialization code in module life cycle hooks

Note: register DI in the life cycle hooks is an example of interacting with the DI service (that might be configured outside of your project)

See 
https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Module-System#lifecycle-methods

Abp provides convenient way to register classes that follows the convention

IocManager.RegisterAssemblyByConvention(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

Note: the recommended way is to only have a abp module per assembly

See 
https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Dependency-Injection#registering-dependencies

Comment: Note: the recommended way is to only have an abp module per assembly

what does that means ?

Comment: First of all, assembly is usually the dll or exe generated by a project. E.g [abp asp net core assembly](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/773d6355dd61a412ba9cdf8bae0a63c637138bbb/src/Abp.AspNetCore/Abp.AspNetCore.csproj#L8) contains only a single abp module, namely AbpAspNetCoreModule

Comment: I got [response on aspnetBoilerplate's Github](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/4480).
 each project is considered as an assembly.